Creating multiple business accounts and linking employee accounts under a Firebase project
I'm working on a side project and I've run into a problem trying to figure out how I would have users sign up in my app. I would want to use Firebase because it's easier for me and the Realtime Database is something I'd need in the project (still new at mobile dev).
The business admin would create an account on my app, where they would send data to the firebase db. I'd add their business_id as a column in the table.
The business' employees should be able to create their own accounts as well but my issue comes with figuring out how to link those employees to their respective business so that they can only read the data from their business and not other companies' data.
Can this be done in Firebase?
Also, what would be the simplest way to do this? As I'd want to make the login and linking process easy since my clients are not tech-savvy.
Ideally I would want that the business admin could link the employee accounts from a web portal using OTPs or pins of some sort so I don't have to intervene every time an employee joins or leaves the company. But I'm still trying to figure out the mechanics of it.
Any tips or ideas would be helpful!
I've been looking into firebase to do this but I haven't found any recent data on this whether it's possible or not. Other option would be to make the whole authentication and db on my own but idk if that's the better option right now, I'll see depending on the answers I get if I should just do it in Springboot + mysql and integrate everything together after.

There are 2 ways to do this
Method 1:
You can create a unique key or ID like 6 or 8 alphanumeric characters. Which will be uniquely linked with the business account not the same as the business id. business admin can share this with employees who want to create their account and while filling in their details employees can mention this key which can link them to business.
Method 2:
Alternatively, if you don't want to share a key then employees can search for a business account during registration and request a business to verify the employee and if an employee belongs to a business after verification you can link them to a business account.

Thanks those are good options, would this be possible with firebase too?

Yes, you can use any database as the logic resides on the server. if the answer was useful do give it a vote.
